# How to select which sound output device to use for /dev/dsp OSS emulation?

Tags: audio, hdmi, arch-linux, alsa

I have a system with two sound devices and am using sound via HDMI out. This is Card 1, Device 7, Subdevice 0, so I set in my `/usr/share/alsa.conf`:

```
defaults.ctl.card 1
defaults.pcm.card 1
defaults.pcm.device 7
defaults.pcm.subdevice 0
```

This gives me sound in ALSA applications. Now I want to run an old program that needs OSS, so I installed `alsa-oss` and did `sudo modprobe snd-pcm-oss snd-mixer-oss`. When I run the old program, I get sound, but only from the analog line out, not from HDMI, so the OSS emulation uses the first card.

How can I tell the OSS emulation to use the second card instead?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sound/alsa/OSS-Emulation.txt) says:

> ALSA supports the following OSS device files:
>
> PCM:
>
> ```
>       /dev/dspX
>       /dev/adspX
> ```
>
> [...]
>   Unlike the real OSS, ALSA cannot use the device files more than the
>   assigned ones.  For example, the first card cannot use /dev/dsp1 or
>   /dev/dsp2, but only /dev/dsp0 and /dev/adsp0. [...]
>   As seen above, PCM and MIDI may have two devices.  Usually, the first
>   PCM device (hw:0,0 in ALSA) is mapped to /dev/dsp and the secondary
>   device (hw:0,1) to /dev/adsp (if available).
>
> You can change this device mapping via the module options of
>   snd-pcm-oss and snd-rawmidi.  In the case of PCM, the following
>   options are available for snd-pcm-oss:
>
> ```
>   dsp_map     PCM device number assigned to /dev/dspX
>       (default = 0)
>   adsp_map    PCM device number assigned to /dev/adspX
>       (default = 1)
> ```
>
> For example, to map the third PCM device (hw:0,2) to /dev/adsp0,
>   define like this:
>
> ```
> options snd-pcm-oss adsp_map=2
> ```
>
> The options take arrays.  For configuring the second card, specify
>   two entries separated by comma.  For example, to map the third PCM
>   device on the second card to /dev/adsp1, define like below:
>
> ```
> options snd-pcm-oss adsp_map=0,2
> ```

Comment: The problem is, to my understanding, my HDMI is not hw:0,1 but hw:1,7. How would I set /dev/dsp to be hw:1,7 then?

Comment: You have to tell the old program to use `/dev/(a)dsp1`.

Comment: I never get /dev/(a)dsp1, I only get /dev/dsp. My sound hardware is funny in that way, it seems to use the snd_hda_intel and NVidia's proprietary graphics driver somehow installs a second device, but when I blacklist snd_hda_intel, HDMI sound is also gone

Comment: Both use the `snd-hda-intel` driver. You get `adsp` for device 1 by default. Aren't you using the `adsp_map` option?

Comment: If I do `sudo modprobe snd_pcm_oss adsp_map=0` I do get `/dev/adsp`, but sound still comes from the analog audio. When using `dsp_map=1` or anything other than 0, I not even get `/dev/dsp`. I think I will be running the video signal through DVI via two adapters to strip the audio, and use onboard analog sound instead. It's only a monitor with built-in speakers anyway.

Comment: To map card 1, device 7 to (a)dsp1, use `(a)dsp_map=0,7`.

Comment: No, still only sound from the analog audio.

Comment: Did you tell the old program to use `/dev/(a)dsp1`?

Comment: Using `(a)dsp_map=0,7` only gives me `/dev/(a)dsp`, no `(a)dsp1`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31940/discussion-between-rabejens-and-cl).

Answer (score -2):

I got this working on my system.

[http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=145874][1]

Let me know if you got it to work.
Very interested.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.